# Should a web-crawler pick up queries?

Tags: html, web-crawler

The latest days I have coded a web-crawler. The only question I have left is, does "standard" web-crawlers crawl links queries like this one:
https://www.google.se/?q=stackoverflow
or does it skip the queries and pick them up like this:
https://www.google.se

Comment: Haha... when I looked at the links for a second I thought, "Shoot, www.Google.StackExchange!!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you are referring to crawling for some sort of indexing of web resources:

The answer is very long but in short my opinion is that: 
if you have this "page/resource": https://www.google.se/?q=stackoverflow  pointed to by many other pages (i.e. it has a large in-link degree) then not integrating it to your index might mean that you miss a very important node in the webgraph. On the other hand, imagine how many links of this type google.com/q="query" are there on the web. Probably a huge number so this would certainly be a huge overhead for your crawler/indexer system.

Comment: I just thought of this as well. Do you have any recommendations on how to handle it, or references to a page which talks about this problem?

Comment: A very simplistic solution would be to set a threshold and if a resource's in-link degree is larger than that threshold crawl it and add it to the index, otherwise ignore it.

Comment: I certainly don't have a pointer to give you. Not sure that such a pointer exists!

Answer (score 0):

If the link is visited using a GET request then yes, a web browser should crawl it.

There are still lots of websites which use the query string to identify which content is being requested, e.g. in a blog /article.php?article_id=754. If web browsers didn't follow links like these then lots of content on the web would not get indexed.

Comment: True. Thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: I have a link similar to the one you posted. I am looking to crawl a particular site. How do I go on about creating a web service to crawl the website?

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, many websites which offer search ban search engine results pages using /robots.txt.

You do need to crawl pages with cgi args, but it's necessary for a robust crawler to understand cgi args which are either irrelevant or harmful.

Crawling using urchin cgi args (utm_campaign etc.) just means you're going to see duplicate content.

Sites that add a session cgi arg to every fetch not only have duplicate content, but some especially clever sites give an error if you show up with a stale cgi arg! This makes them nearly impossible to crawl.

Some sites have links with cgi args which are dangerous to access., e.g. "delete" buttons in a publicly-editable database.

Google webmaster tools has a way to tell google which cgi args should be ignored for your site, but that's not helpful to other search engines. I don't know of anyone working on a robots.txt extension for this issue.

Over the past 4 years, blekko has accreted an awful regex of args which we delete out of URLs. It's a pretty long list!

Comment: Since you seems to be on Stack Overflow to promote your own product, I would strongly suggest you to read the about [Limits for self-promotion in answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers), [How do I mention my own products in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15787/how-do-i-mention-my-own-products-in-answers) and [the FAQ about promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).